# Journals to read in order to keep up to date with interesting research

Tags: encryption

I'd love suggestions from crypto.stack as to academic journals to read. They can range from introductory to advanced, as long as it's free (requires no access fees).

Feel free to edit this question if you're looking for specific fields, too.

Comment: If you want to keep up to date with state of the art research, journals in this field are not the best place to look at (it is quite common that mainly selected papers from various good venues are invited to journals). It makes much more sense to look at proceedings of good conferences and workshops (e.g., from the [IACR](http://www.iacr.org/)) as they have a much more timely dissemination of results. Furthermore, you will find lots of these papers (and extended versions) for free on [IACRs eprint service](http://eprint.iacr.org/). Anyways, I think the questions is not on-topic here.

Comment: `Feel free to edit this question if you're looking for specific fields, too.` since you're asking on http://crypto.stackexchange.com, the field is pretty much defined

Comment: @DrLecter is correct – Requests for **reference recommendations** are ***“off-topic”*** here. For details, see: [Do we want “literature recommendations” and similar “list/subjective questions”?](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1/do-we-want-literature-recommendations-and-similar-list-subjective-questions)

Answer (score 4):

In the specific field of cryptography, journals are not much actually used. Since the 1980s, cryptographers have taken to the habit of publishing their articles through *conferences*; thus, the conference proceedings serve as "formal publication". For instance, Matsui's linear cryptanalysis method, first applied to the DES algorithm, was presented to Eurocrypt'93 and thus published through the [proceedings](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48285-7_33), which became one of the "LNCS" books from Springer-Verlag (this means "Lecture Notes in Computer Science"; proceedings of Eurocrypt'93 are LNCS 765, and Matsui's article consists of pages 386 to 397 in that book).

There long has been a single journal for cryptographers, the [Journal of Cryptology](http://www.iacr.org/jofc/), which is not used for publishing new results; rather, it mostly houses extended versions of particularly noteworthy articles which were already published as conference proceedings.

In later years, things have changed a bit, but mostly by having *more* conferences, not more journals. If you want to keep up to date with cryptography, you go to conferences.

As @DrLecter points out, cryptographers have also embraced the Internet, with an [electronic archive](http://eprint.iacr.org/) for new results (but these ones have not been peer-reviewed, so while you get recent results that way, you may get *wrong* results as well).

Comment: +1 thats excatly what I had in mind :) Additionally it is worth noting that IACR eprint has an info for every paper indicating whether it is unpublished or where it has been published previously (at the moment most of the papers there are extended versions of previously published results, since the paper limits for proceedings are quite low and thus the proceedings versions are typically quite squeezed versions - omitting most of the proofs - and thus not that nice to read). So one finds lots of recently published papers or papers already accepted and to be published soon there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Journal of Cryptology
2. Journal of Cryptographic Engineering
3. International Journal of Applied Cryptography
4. Journal of Computer Security
5. TISSEC